# XMPP application need to filter other clients e.g. Pidgin out

Tags: xmpp

We develop an application that supposed to enable interaction between peers using the application only. We would like to differentiate between users logged in via our app and on the common chat client e.g. Pidgin.

There is an observation: if we have the same user name logged in through both our app and Pidgin, the app looses stanzas from time to time, because they only delivered to Pidgin and vice versa.

I have already started considering tracking some specific jid for the user of our app by checking the app specific postfix e.g. MyName@OurServer/OurApp (OurApp is that postfix). But if the same user name logged in on both our app and Pidgin, how can we make the server delivering stanzas to our client only?

Answer (score 2):

The resource identifier (what you call the 'postfix') is not a reliable way to detect your application. The server is able to change it to anything it feels like. Also, although unlikely in practice, the user may enter this resource string in their client, causing trouble.

The correct way to identify the type of client is via its presence. The standard way is to use [XEP-0115: Entity Capabilities](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0115.html) and [XEP-0030: Service Discovery](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0030.html#info-nodes). Your client would include a particular identifying feature in its service discovery result.

Once the full JID of your client is identified, always use that to communicate with it. Use either `<iq>` stanzas for request/response, or `<message>` stanzas with a custom payload (no `<body>`).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you send to the full JID, not just the base JID.

```
Full JID: MyName@OurServer/OurApp
Base JID: MyName@OurServer
```

The second version can have a couple of different outcomes, depending on the server and it's configuration.  Using the full JID will send only to that client connection.

Answer (score 1):

The "postfix" is called resource in XMPP. You can send XMPP packets to a bare JID ( user@domian.com ) or to a full JID ( user@domain.com/resource ). You can easily use the resource to identify your client and you could also check the client software with Service Discovery, see [Example 8](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0030.html#info-basic).

Comment: Thanks, that works. We had a problem of not always appending resource to the "to" field. Handled by enforcing the rule, no single stanza is sent without the resource appended.